# Specs2 await doesn't fail inside of a Scope

Tags: specs2

When using Specs2(v 2.3.13) await, I have noticed that in some cases it doesn't fail.  Specifically I have observed that if the "await" times out inside of a Scope, then it doesn't fail.

```
"Awaiting a failed future should fail" in {
  Future.failed(throw new Exception()).map(_ => success).await // Fails Correctly
}
"Awaiting a timed out future should fail" in {
  Future(Thread.sleep(5000)).map(_ => success).await // Fails Correctly
}
"Awaiting a failed scope should fail" in new Scope {
  failure // Fails Correctly
}
"Awaiting a failed future in a scope should fail" in new Scope {
  Future.failed(throw new Exception()).map(_ => success).await // Fails Correctly
}
"Awaiting a timed out future in a scope should fail" in new Scope {
  Future(Thread.sleep(5000)).map(_ => success).await  // DOES NOT FAIL
}
```

Am I misunderstanding the usage, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.await` implicit on a `Future[T]` just creates a `Result` which will fail if there is a time-out. However no exception will be thrown hence that result will not escape that `Scope` trait.

To workaround this you need to use `Matchers` and specify what you expect of your value of type `T` in `Future[T]`:

```
Future(Thread.sleep(5000)).map(_ => 1) must be_==(1).await
```

This will correctly show

```
[info] x Awaiting a timed out future in a scope should fail
[error]  Timeout after 1 second (TestSpec.scala:35)
```